# How to rectify this VBA Macro compile error?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel Macro. I recorded a very simple macro (typed 'a' in cell A1) and saved it for testing. When I run the macro, it gives me a compile error. I suppose there is something wrong with my settings. The image is attached below.

Error screenshot:
[image]

Code used:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Type. = "a"
    Range("A2").Count
End Sub
```

Please check this short video where I recorded my screen while creating the macro.
https://youtu.be/clYd5nc2fN0

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You cannot expect people to click unknown links and should paste the screenshot into the post itself.

Comment: Something is 'wrong with your Macro Recorder'. This is what I get:     `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "a"` : `Range("A2").Select`

Comment: @GoodJuJu I did try pasting the screenshot in the post itself but it did not allow me to do it since I have low number of posts and credibility. SO automatically created the link for me. Hope you understand. Please upvote and give a solution.

Comment: No idea how it record `Type.` - that's not VBA syntax, so you got the syntax error.  `Range("A1") = "a"` will add a to A1 on the currently active sheet.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Is there a way to reset these settings anywhere? Not a single macro that I have recorded is working.

Answer (score 1):

I had to re-install office. No other solution worked. Thanks!